# Laravel Homestead : local code folder not appearing in homestead code folder

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

when I navigate to the "home/vagrant" folder inside the homestead environment, it redirects me to "~" path.. The "Code" folder is not showing there.

Here's my Homestead.yaml configuration

[image: Homestead.yaml]

I tried to change the folder map to "~/Code", run the homestead reloader, restart the virtual box.. still not working..

Comment: when you are in the home/vagrant directory and run the `dir` command, what do you get?

Comment: Completely not sure if it helps, but have you tried mapping `C:/Users/{user}/Code/Laravel` to `/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel` ?

Comment: @AlfredoEM it shows the files of my root directory or in short, it redirects me to the root folder "vagrant@homestead:~$".... the files are .bash_history, .bash_logout,.ssh etc

Comment: @JohnDoe same result :(

Comment: Any warning from the virtualbox load script?

Comment: @JohnDoe there's none, not sure if this is because I'm not an admin user to the PC where I installed the homestead

Answer (score 0):

step1- `vagrant up`

step2- `vagrant ssh`

step3 - create a code folder `sudo mkdir ~/code`

step4- put all permissions `sudo chmod -R 777 ~/code`

step5- configure your `Homestead.yaml`

my Homestead yaml:

folders: - map: `~/Documents/GitHub` <-- i put my projects in Documents/github , put your folder route--> to: `/home/vagrant/code`

sites: - `map: okalaschool.test` to: `/home/vagrant/code/surfschool/public`

databases: - homestead - `okala`

variables: - key: APP_ENV value: local

step5- save changes and run `vagrant reload --provision`

step6- `put vagrant ssh`

and ready